# How to form flexible expandable filter with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, filter, filtering

I need to build a universal filter with TypeScript using operators 'OR' and 'AND'. There should be a way to use range and multiselect filters as well.
But I'm new to OOP and can't grasp how I should do it using classes.
The filter request to backend should look something like this and there has to be a way to expand them if there is a new type:

```
[
  { field: 'id', operator: '=', value: 12 },
  'OR',
  { field: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'testName' },
  'OR',
  [
    { field: 'age', operator: '>=', value: '20' },
    'AND',
    { field: 'age', operator: '=<', value: '30' }
  ]
]
```

I form an array of objects looking like this and feed to a class that forms filters:

```
[
    {
        field: 'id',
        type: 'default',
        value: 12
    },
    {
        field: 'id2',
        type: 'default',
        value: 13
    },
    {
        field: 'name',
        type: 'default',
        value: 'yulya'
    },
    {
        field: 'age',
        type: 'range',
        value: '20 - 30'
    }
]
```

The class FilterParameters looks like this, however, it is not expandable:

```
export class FilterParameters {
    filter: (string | object | number)[]
    constructor() {
        this.filter = []
    }
    createFilter(receivedFields: (object)[]) {
        let filterArr:(object)[] = []
        let defaultFilter = receivedFields.filter((item)  => item.type === 'default')
        let rangeFilter = receivedFields.filter(item => item.type === 'range')
        defaultFilter.forEach((item:any) => {
            let defaultFilterObj = {
                field: item.field,
                operator: '=',
                value: item.value
            }
            filterArr.push(defaultFilterObj)
        })
        rangeFilter.forEach((item:any) => {
            let conditionArr = []
            let startCondition = item.value.split(' ')[0]
            let endCondition = item.value.split(' ').pop()
            let objStartCondition = {
                field: item.field,
                operator: '>=',
                value: startCondition
            }
            let objEndCondition = {
                field: item.field,
                operator: '=<',
                value: endCondition
            }
            conditionArr.push(objStartCondition)
            conditionArr.push('AND')
            conditionArr.push(objEndCondition)
            filterArr.push(conditionArr)
        })
        this.filter = filterArr.map((e, i) => i < filterArr.length - 1  ? [e, 'OR'] : [e]).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
        return this.filter
    }
}
```

How can I create a class that forms filters and easily expandable?

Comment: Why do you convert the array? How can you represent `[{ field: 'id', operator: '=', value: 12 }, 'AND', { field: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'testName' }]` or `[{ field: 'percentage', operator: '>', value: '20.123' }, 'AND', { field: 'percentage', operator: '<', value: '20.124' }]` with the new array?

Comment: IMHO a simple representation for such a filter is a binary tree like `{ OR: [{ field: 'id', operator: '=', value: 12 }, {OR: [{ field: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'testName' }, AND: [{ field: 'age', operator: '>=', value: '20' }, { field: 'age', operator: '=<', value: '30' }]]}]}`. This will also clarify the precedence in cases like `[{ field: 'id', operator: '=', value: 12 }, 'AND', { field: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'testName' }, 'OR', { field: 'age', operator: '>=', value: '20' }]`.

Comment: The type for this filter is `interface Or { OR: [Filter, Filter]; }`, `interface And { AND: [Filter, Filter]; }`, `type Filter = Or | And | { field: string; operator: string; value: string | number; };`

Comment: I need to take an array `[
     {
        field: 'name',
        type: 'default',
        value: 'yulya'
    },
    {
        field: 'age',
        type: 'range',
        value: '20 - 30'
    }
]` and transform it into  `[
  { field: 'id', operator: '=', value: 12 },
  'OR',
  { field: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'testName' },
  'OR',
  [
    { field: 'age', operator: '>=', value: '20' },
    'AND',
    { field: 'age', operator: '=<', value: '30' }
  ]
]` to send to backend and receive a response

Comment: Is the precedence specified? What does the backend do with `[{ field: 'id', operator: '=', value: 12 }, 'AND', { field: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'testName' }, 'OR', { field: 'age', operator: '>=', value: '20' }]`? First `AND` or first `OR` or from left to right or from right to left?

Comment: This is a fun one!  For OOP this will involve multiple classes and interfaces, not just one.  We need builders, we need parsers, we need specific types.  I will play with it and share what I come up with.

Comment: @kuroi.kasa is the requirement really that you want to take an object with a property like `value: '20 - 30'` and parse it?  If I were designing a whole system I would not represent a range as a string.  But ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things that I would change if I were designing this from the ground up as your current approach has a number of limitations.  For example the input array always uses `'OR'` with no way to use `'AND'` or create groupings.

I am assuming that your input format and output format are fixed and our task is just to create a more extensible way to map from the input to the output.  The first thing that I do is define those types.

Each filter of the input looks like this, and we expect to receive an array of them.

```
interface InputFilter {
    field: string;
    type: string;
    value: any;
}
```

The output is more complicated due to the nesting.

```
interface OutputFilterElement {
    field: string;
    operator: string;
    value: any;
}

type Joiner = 'OR' | 'AND';

type OutputFilterArray = Array<OutputFilterElement | Joiner | OutputFilterArray>

type OutputFilter = OutputFilterElement | OutputFilterArray;
```

We want parsing to be an extensible system that allows for adding new input types and mapping them to their outputs.  If we want to add a new type, what information do we need?  We need to know the `type` string that it matches and how it maps input objects of this type to outputs.  We can write that as an `interface`.

```
interface TypeParser {
    type: string;
    parse: (input: InputFilter) => OutputFilter;
}
```

We want our `FilterParameters` class to just know about the `TypeParser` interface and to not know or care what concrete implementations of that interface exist.  So we can instantiate this class by passing any number of `TypeParser` objects as an argument to the `constructor`.

The class has a public method `parse` to parse an array of input filters based on its available type parsers.  It looks for the matching parser and then delegates the actual parsing.

```
export class FilterParameters {
    private readonly typeParsers: TypeParser[];

    /**
     * construct an isntance of the FilterParser by passing the TypeParsers to handle specific types
     */
    constructor(...typeParsers: TypeParser[]) {
        this.typeParsers = typeParsers;
    }

    /**
     * helper function parses each element of the array
     * might throw an error
     */
    private parseOne(input: InputFilter): OutputFilter {
        // find the parser for this type
        const parser = this.typeParsers.find(p => p.type === input.type);
        if (!parser) {
            throw new Error(`no filter found for type ${input.type}`);
        }
        return parser.parse(input);
    }

    /**
     * handle an array of individual filters by assuming an 'OR' relationship
     */
    public parse(input: InputFilter[]): OutputFilter {
        // use flatMap to insert 'OR' between elements
        return input.flatMap(
            (condition, i) => {
                const parsed = this.parseOne(condition);
                return i === 0 ? [parsed] : ['OR', parsed]
            }
        );
        // do we want to catch errors here? or allow them to be thrown?
    }
}
```

I don't think it makes sense to use classes if they don't need any sort of instance so I am creating our concrete implementations of `TypeParser` as objects which fulfill the interface.

```
const EqualityParser: TypeParser = {
    type: 'default',
    parse: ({ field, value }: InputFilter): OutputFilter => {
        return ({
            field,
            // operator is always equals for default filter
            operator: '=',
            value
        });
    }
}

const RangeParser: TypeParser = {
    type: 'range',
    parse: ({ field, value }: InputFilter): OutputFilter => {
        // split based on hyphen with optional spaces before and after
        const [min, max] = value.split(/\s*-\s*/);
        // are these always numbers? should we use parseFloat?
        return ([{
            field,
            operator: '>=',
            value: min
        },
            'AND',
        {
            field,
            operator: '<=',
            value: max
        }]);
    }
}
```

In order to parse your input using these two parsers, you would write:

```
const filterer = new FilterParameters(EqualityParser, RangeParser);
const output = filterer.parse(input);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N7bKow)